# How to handle pricing and design for logos on small scale web projects?

Tags: estimation, subcontracting

I often do small projects, complete web sites, in the $1500 - $2000 range for small business owners.

Where I get stuck is in the pricing for designing logos (I can do it - I've got some skills, but I'm a not a graphic designer - so this takes me forever).

Not only is logo design subjective, but part of a 'creative' process - so it's impossible for me to estimate this - and truthfully, I'd rather outsource this part of the project - but handle that for the client.

Where I need some help is how to price out and approach logo development, so that I can outsource it, get the web contract completed, have a happy client - and not lose hours or days trying to do the logo development myself.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Do you belong to a network of freelancers that you can call on for assistance? I only ask this, because I don't do design, but I know people who do, and I constantly refer to them if clients ask for graphic design help/creation

Comment: I do have some options, and can certainly build out my network as an option, but I would love to hear from graphic designers on how to go about rolling their services into an overall web site development project quote, keeping in mind the total cost bracket for these types of web projects are between $1500 - $2000 - we don't want exhaust the budget on logo design.

Also, if anybody uses 3rd party services that they feel are reliable, I'd love to hear their suggested approach and advice.

In both cases, an estimation of appropriate fees and scope of services delivered would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Why running away from outsourcing the design phase? This is something I do all the time, as well as 90% of other freelancers.

Pros:
- you have more time for coding
- a client will get professional design
- you can earn some extra for taking percentage on the design (don't need to if you don't want to)
- you keep the client and tell him you're capable of solving things out of your expertise

Ideally you will connect your design and the client to some online service like basecamp or trello where the client will have a direct access to design sketches and will be able to influence the design. You will be like a mediator there.

The latest thing I would do it try to design if I don't have eye for it. It will not only be ugly but it will take you a week for the work a professional can do in 1 day.

Note: a logo design is very cheap. I've seen people paying $30 or $50 for it on odesk or elance. And those designers are able to finish it in a day or less. And the final output does not look ugly at all, on the contrary.

Comment: Great answer. I like the idea of using an online project collaboration tool like basecamp or trello. elance looks like a great option - I will try that approach for a personal project first.